# Why must write O AS INT and can't write (INT)O

Tags: c#

I've found in the Jon Skeet's book an example of using **as** operator with the types, which allows **null** value.

```
using System;

class A
{
    static void PrintValueAsInt32(object o)
    {
        int? nullable = o as int?; // can't write int? nullable = (int?)o
        Console.WriteLine(nullable.HasValue ?
                          nullable.Value.ToString() :
                          "null");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        PrintValueAsInt32(5);
        PrintValueAsInt32("some string");
    }
}
```

I can't understand, why I can't write `int? nullable = (int?)o`? When I try to do that, I'm getting an exception.

Comment: You're getting an exception because the `(int?)o` syntax throws an exception when the cast is invalid whereas the `o as int?` syntax returns a null when the cast is invalid. The book should explain that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the [`as operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) is performing a check before *cast*.If types are not convertible to each other then it just returns *null* and avoids the `InvalidCastException`.

You are getting an exception when you try to perfom *explicit* cast because in the second call you are passing a string to the method which is not convertible to `int?`

Comment: +1. For completeness, there is a [good blog post from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx) that explain the differences in more detail.